# How to use Krb5LoginModule and give it a user/pass in unix

Tags: security, kerberos, jaas

I need to login using kerberos on a unix machine to call a URL using a windows network.  I can use the useTicketCache=true in windows and everything works fine.  How do I do this from a unix box and just pass in the user/pass to my java program instead of using the ticket cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way you should go. The human itself should obtain the TGT on Windows logon. You access the TGT then ot obtain a service ticket from KDC.
If your unix setup does not use winbind to perform auth, so you don't have access to a prepopulated credential cache, you have three options:

1. Use winbind to manage your unix users in AD
2. Perform a unix `kinit`
3. Pass a `Username` and/or `PasswordCallback` to `new LoginContext`.

I would favor 1 or 2.

Option two would work like this from Java:

```
Runtime.exec("kinit " + upn);
// Obtain the input stream of the forked process
is.write(password);
// Check exit code
```

Now you have a native valid TGT in your credential cache. Java can pick this up now and request further service tickets.

Comment: thanks for the info, is there a way I can call kinit and give it the info that I have in my krb5.ini file?  do i need root to do this?